Stabilizing Tests Against Variable Server Response Times
Errors vary from test to test. I believe this is due to different server response times. We are currently including "timeout" and "waitfor" in our code to counter this. Please let us know if there are any other measures to stabilize server speed other than the above.
I believe this is due to different server response times. We are currently including "timeout" and "waitfor" in our code to counter this.

Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some code demonstrating what you're talking about/what you've tried to your post?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Managing variable server response times using "timeout" and "waitfor" is the right thing to do in a Playright tests.

We can try to run tests in headless mode to speed up execution and reduce resource consumption.\
If we use Playwright's introspection events to wait for elements to be actionable before performing actions, the this can help reduce the need for artificial timeouts and reduce flakiness.\
Additionaly, we can mock the network request and at the same time try use a network caching tool like playwright-network-cache to cache network responses.
Ref https://dev.to/vitalets/supercharge-your-e2e-tests-with-playwright-network-cache-58jm

